# Cannot store selected range into variable

Tags: vba

I have the following code that selects all used cells starting from the cell specified.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim ranged_select As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Worksheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("C2")

'Find Last Row and Column
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range
  sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
```

But how come for the last line
`sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select`
I cannot assign it to a variable? I want the variable to be a range. I have tried assigning this variable `Dim used_ranged as Range` but it gives me 'Run-time error '91':'

Here is the data and what it looks like when I run the code which just selects  the data starting from C2.

[image]

Comment: `Set StartCell = sht.Range("C2") ` or it will default to whatever is the ActiveSheet.  If you want the range in a variable then you need to drop the `.Select`, since that doesn't return anything you can assign to your varaible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have made the two changes but the same error code is still popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim range_select As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Worksheet1")
Set StartCell = sht.Range("C2")    '<< always be explicit about the parent sheet

'Find Last Row and Column
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'drop the .Select
Set range_select = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```